# First connect gives unsupported MIME type, but after browser refreshes works fine?

Tags: css, socket.io, mime

After deploying the app on App Engine -- at first connect the *Chrome* client throws the following error.

```
"Refused to apply style from 'https://tournypoker.wl.r.appspot.com/styles/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."
```

After a couple of browser refresh the error goes away and everything seems to work fine. I tried to follow some of the other threads here on a similar issue, but no luck.

Here is some code that shows how the style sheet is loaded in index.jade --

html(lang="en" ng-app="app")

```
head
    title Poker
    link(href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css")
body
    #content(ng-view)
    script(type="text/javascript", src="socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/libs/angular.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/app.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/controllers/lobby.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/controllers/table.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/controllers/chat.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/services/sounds.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/directives/seat.js")
```

Comment: Hi Shareq, welcome to stack overflow. Please add some code, for example, how the stylesheet is loaded. I guess the mime type is okay, but the url returning a 404 error which is type `text/html`

Comment: Hi Archer -- I added the code segment that loads the stylesheet above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out GCP app engine standard environment does not support websockets.
This app was trying to establish websockets -- and the side effect was the above.
I changed my app.yaml to use the app engine flex environment -- that fixed this problem along with the websocket issue.

## [START gae_quickstart_yaml]

runtime: nodejs
env: flex

network:
session_affinity: true

manual_scaling:
instances: 1
resources:
cpu: 1
memory_gb: 0.5
disk_size_gb: 10

## [END gae_quickstart_yaml]